# jQuery .hover() seems to "disappear" after a while

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

```
$('img.questSign').hover( function() { 
    $('img.questSign').attr('src', '/media/quest-sign-small-hover.png');
},
function(){
    $('img.questSign').attr('src', '/media/quest-sign-small.png');
});
```

This code works quite awesome, when the page has been loaded freshly.
But after a while it seems to be stop working.
The picture does not change on hover.

**ADDITION:

I ran a long-term test with all major browsers and it seems that this very special problem only appears in the new Firefox 5 beta. Problem fixed with new Firefox Update**

Comment: Are you sure something doesn't break your script? Do you get JS errors when it stops working? Code looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I use Firefox 5beta, + standard webdev tools.
Maybe I have to set a window interval to update the events when the window is not active for a while....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('img.questSign').hover(function() { 
    $(this).attr('src', '/media/quest-sign-small-hover.png');
}, function() {
    $(this).attr('src', '/media/quest-sign-small.png');
});
```

Your old code would misbehave with multiple `img.questSign`s on the page.

Comment: @daemonfire300: Are you wrapping it in a `$(document).ready`?

Comment: of course I do. The code works fine, but it just stops working after a while.
That is the really weird thing.

Comment: @daemonfire300: I think we might need to see a live demo.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a timeout like this:

```
$('img.questSign').hover(function () {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    $(this).attr('src', '/media/quest-sign-small-hover.png');
}, function () {
    var e = $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function () {
        e.attr('src', '/media/quest-sign-small.png');
    }, 3000)); // 3 sec
});
```

Comment: Yes, but why should a timeout fix the issue of the event disappearing after a while.